# Streak Count Below 0

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Dataframe and i'd like to count streaks in this manner.

[image]

So far i have tried

```py
dataframe['streak'] = dataframe['close'].groupby((dataframe['close'] <= dataframe['close'].shift(1)).cumsum()).cumcount() +1
```

but this does not go under 0

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more if/else-ish approach:

```py
import pandas as pd

def calc_streaks(series: pd.Series):
    
    # logic tables
    geq = series >= series.shift(1) # True if rising
    eq = series == series.shift(1)  # True if equal
    logic_table = pd.concat([geq, eq], axis=1)

    streaks = [0] # holds the streak duration, starts with 0
    
    for row in logic_table.iloc[1:].itertuples(): # iterate through logic table
        if row[2]: # same value as before
            streaks.append(0)
            continue
        last_value = streaks[-1]
        if row[1]: # higher value than before
            streaks.append(last_value + 1 if last_value >= 0 else 1) # increase or reset to +1
        else: # lower value than before
            streaks.append(last_value - 1 if last_value < 0 else -1) # decrease or reset to -1
    
    return streaks

df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 20.00), (2, 20.50), (3, 20.75), (4, 19.75), (5, 19.50), (6, 19.35), (7, 19.35), (8, 19.40)], columns=["day", "closing"]).set_index("day")
df["streak"] = calc_streaks(df["closing"])
print(df)
```

Results:

```
     closing  streak
day                 
1      20.00       0
2      20.50       1
3      20.75       2
4      19.75      -1
5      19.50      -2
6      19.35      -3
7      19.35       0
8      19.40       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you can achieve this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def streaks(df):
    diff = df['close'] < df['close'].shift(1)
    eq = df['close'] == df['close'].shift(1)
    
    def count(x):
        n = 0 if count.called == 0 or eq[count.sum] else 1
        r = np.arange(n, len(x) + n)
        if count.called % 2 == 1:
            r = -r

        count.called += 1
        count.sum += len(x)
        return pd.Series(r, x.index)
    count.called = 0
    count.sum = 0
    
    return df.groupby((diff != diff.shift(1)).cumsum()).apply(count).array

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'close': [20, 20.5, 20.75, 19.75, 19.50, 19.35, 19.35, 19.40, 19.39, 19.41, 19.42]})
df['streaks'] = streaks(df)
print(df)
```

Gives:

```
    close  streaks
0   20.00        0
1   20.50        1
2   20.75        2
3   19.75       -1
4   19.50       -2
5   19.35       -3
6   19.35        0
7   19.40        1
8   19.39       -1
9   19.41        1
10  19.42        2
```